# Track WCF REST using GoogleAnalyticsTracker

Tags: wcf, rest, google-analytics

I have a restful WCF at http://myapp.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc that returns json data. The wcf is in Azure right now.
I want to track the usage of the WCf using googleAnalyticsTracker. All clients that use my WCf by sending http request to it, i want them tracked by googleAnalytics.

I have created an accout at googleAnalytics and provide the same url as above for the service to track.

The only operatin GetData() in Service1.svc is called when that http.../Service1.svc is browsed, with this code for Trakcer in GetData():

```
Tracker tracker = new Tracker("UA-xxxxx-x", "http://myapp.cloudapp.net/");

        //var request = svcSecurityContext;
        tracker.SetCustomVariable(1, "Time", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        tracker.SetCustomVariable(2, "UserName", "myname");

        tracker.SetCustomVariable(3, "Service accessed",     OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To.ToString());

        tracker.TrackPageView("My API - Create", "api/create");
```

The service return the data and i wheb go to mydashboard at googleAnalytics, i cannot see Visits being incremented. I need help to figure out if i am using googleanalyticstracker correctly.

Is it possible to do like iam doing using googleanalytics with a wcf or it just can be used with web pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Google Analytics Tracker?
https://github.com/maartenba/GoogleAnalyticsTracker

The code works for ASP.NET Web API, but could be used for a WCF.  For WCF, I would create a behavior with this code.

Comment: Yes, Bart. i am using the same code as in that link for GoogleAnalytics, but it is not working, nothing is tracked in my google account.
I would like to know more about what you say about behavior. Do you mean that i can create a behavior to make the googleAnalytics work? i dont know how to do that but if you can provide links, tutoril or code i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

it works but GoogleAnalytics does not show the stats because of it takes some time to get the updated stats. For me it tok about 1 hour. 
This link show how you simply can show stats from today:

[real-time-stats-with-google-analytics](http://www.thetechfaq.com/2008/03/12/real-time-stats-with-google-analytics/)

Answer (score 0):

It works well but I don't see my custom variables in Google Analytics !

```
        using (Tracker tracker = new Tracker("UA-xxxxx-x", "http://myapp.cloudapp.net/"))
        {                
            tracker.SetCustomVariable(1, "User id", uid);
            tracker.SetCustomVariable(2, "Test", "ok");
            tracker.SetCustomVariable(3, "Test2", "fgd");
            tracker.SetCustomVariable(4, "Test3", "PPP");
            tracker.SetCustomVariable(5, "Test4", "dfsPPP");

            tracker.TrackPageView("PortecarteService", "ws/GetListFolder");
        }
```

thanks